# Xcode error to store data due to "Info.plist"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, info.plist

I'm trying to store some data, but every time I execute the proper command to do it, I get this message on the console:

> GlassyFy[3435:69406] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")

I've been looking for solutions about Info.plist (it seems to be the main reason) but I can't find the damn file... or maybe I'm wrong and that's not the reason of this problem.

Comment: This is usually related to adding Scene Delegate code without knowing all the steps. Unless you are supporting iOS 13 you should undo all the changes related to scene delegate

Answer (score 1):

go into Xcode project build settings and search for `INFOPLIST_FILE` or simply `plist`. You should see if there is a folder noted at all, if not write a note into the property field where that Info.plist is or should be, which could in your case look like `GlassyFy/Info.plist`

you can read also the [docu](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/ConfigFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002091-CJBJIEDH) about.

if there is no folder/info.plist than Xcode can also not store your app properties into such file. Search also manually your project folders, maybe even the folder above (`..`) if your project wrote a info.plist in the wrong place.

and here UIScene definition that usually belongs into info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <false/> // < --- see should be false when you have just one.
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key> // the name
        <array> // the info for that Session
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                <string>UIWindowScene</string>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>SceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Main</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>anotherkey</key> //but remember above i wrote false.. 
        <array> // so the property should be <true/> when multiple..
        ....
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So you see here one definition for UIScene named `UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication`, you can have multiple and so such would appear below with similar structure.

when you change the folder of Info.plist make sure to close and open your project and possibly even Xcode before changing more properties